# Running Google Test cases non parallel

Tags: googletest

Because of the resource exhaustion there is a need to run test cases serially, without threads (integration tests for CUDA code). Went through source code (e.g. tweaking `GetThreadCount()`) and trying to find other ways how to influence gmock/gtest framework to run tests serially but found no way out.

Apparently at first did not find any command line arguments that could influence it. Feel like the only way out is to create many binaries or create a script that utilizes `--gtest-filter`. I would not like to mess with secret synchronization primitives between test cases.

Comment: This question is unclear.  Google Test does *not* run tests in parallel.  Do you want your application code (that is being tested) to run serially, without threads?  Or do you want to run many Google Tests in parallel (as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24528821/googletest-how-to-run-tests-asynchronously)?  If your question is the first one, there is not enough information here to answer it.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question. Parallelism is the behavior I would like to change.

Comment: Sorry, it is still unclear.  Google Test does not run tests in parallel.  To run a Google Test-based executable with serial tests, just run the executable as normal.  Does your application code (i.e. the code that you wrote) use parallelism through threads?

Comment: But it uses threads. When we run tests which use CUDA GPU. There is GPU memory exhaustion due to many test cases that have allocated data on GPU - if they are not run asynchronously by the framework it would be fine.

Comment: *What* uses threads?  The GTest framework does *not* run tests asynchronously.  (Although there are some wrinkles with Gtest Death Tests.)  It sounds like your library/application code has a GPU memory leak.  Gtest will run tests one after the other.  If the application code (and your tests themselves) cleans up after itself, there should be no memory exhaustion.

Comment: @NicholasM, it is my understanding that gtest _does_ run tests in parallel, using `pthreads` under the hood, and that no order of execution can be guaranteed between `TEST`s, so you cannot write tests that depend upon each other or use non-reentrant functions.

Comment: Quote from Gtest: "Remember that the test order is undefined, so your code can't depend on a test preceding or following another." From [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60905880/4561887) and [the official source here](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/gmock_for_dummies.md#using-mocks-in-tests).

Comment: @NicholasM, nevermind. Gtest says they determine the order from "a random seed calculated from the current time", but if you want parallel machine execution you must request it. See [advanced.md](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/advanced.md#shuffling-the-tests), under the sections called **"Shuffling the Tests"**, and **"Distributing Test Functions to Multiple Machines"**. It's not explicitly stated, but perhaps parallel test execution is *not* done then even if test order is randomized by default.

Comment: Yet another correction to what I said above: I think gtest only randomizes the `TEST` execution order if you pass `--gtest_shuffle` to your compiled test executable when you run it. Ex: `./my_test_executable --gtest_shuffle`.